# External link in new ECS Experience

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Recently AWS moved to the new ECS Experience UI. Could somebody help me to find where can I find the External Link for my ECS task.

In the previous version of ECS UI it could be found in the container details:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfIQx.png)

Comment: Hello @ragumix - this feature is still being worked on.

For now, to see the link, please feel free to switch back to the old console when you are on the Task details page, by clicking on the "New ECS Experience" toggle near the top left corner. 

Thanks!

Comment: @YuruiZhang ok, thank you, hope it will be added as soon as possible in new UI. Yes, I do the way you proposed, but it's really annoying to move between UI versions.

Answer (score 0):

To describe DNS using the console

1. Open the Amazon ECS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose **Clusters**.
3. Select service name for the task.
4. Review the information in **Configuration & Tasks**, then **Service Discovery**.

[Locate privat DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCH5m.png)

Comment: I have checked suggested path, but there are no entries there.

Comment: It might be different experience between Fargate vs EC2 type of ECS, which type of ECS you are using?

Comment: I am using EC2 type.

Comment: I guess EC2 -> Load Balancer